# Online Java scratchpad like jsfiddle

Tags: java, jsfiddle

I am looking for something like jsfiddle but for java, so that code snippets and classes can be shared and tested.

At the moment, I am using a combination of pastebin and compileonline.com. I would rather not sign up for a huge online compiler service, just a quick and dirty code sharing/testing platform, that provides unique URL's for my code snippets.

I have seen other people asking similar questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320286/is-there-online-compiler-for-java-like-jsfiddle

But there doesn't seem to be just the right tool. Anyone provide any pointers?

Comment: I think that this good question and it is not off-topic.

Comment: runnable.com is good, however, it is a little flaky at times.

Comment: For offline there's http://jpad.io   I'm considering making an online uploader, get in touch and we can discuss it.

Comment: Other useful ones: (Mozilla-sponsored) https://webassembly.studio/ and (Google-sponsored) https://leetcode.com (but you need to select sandbox and explicitly use the "share" button).  Also remoteinterview.io, but there's no file-management there. =\

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I tried using http://ideone.com/.
It supports a bunch of languages, including Java.

Comment: Agree with @Ostap. Just as a warning, be aware of the "private" check. Otherwise, your code will be available online, which could be a problem depending on what are you writing.

Comment: That looks really good, but I cant see any way of defining my own file names. I keep getting compilation errors due to namespace clashes between my classname and whatever filename they are using.

Comment: I also need to log in to edit my code, so as an unregistered user, I have to copy/paste my code and for every bug/compile error I get, I have to create a new snippet with a unique URL, instead of just being able to edit it.

Comment: You can press [Clone] button after your snippet in run. Then, all your code would be copy-pasted automatically.

Comment: The best one I've found is http://runnable.com/. IDE One was erroring out on me.

Comment: What If I need a dependency management as well (eg inclde Jackson to build examples?)

Comment: @Antoniossss usually, these "run a code snippet" services limit the ability to install any software or access network. You can try Cloud9 from Amazon. It may suit your case more.